# Creating a New Object Changes previous Object's Instance Variables

Tags: variables, object, instance

Here is some of my code:

```
           PlayerInfo P1 = new PlayerInfo();
            P1.setInfo(1);
            System.out.println("" + P1.X + "," + P1.Y);
            PlayerInfo P2 =  new PlayerInfo();
            P2.setInfo(2);
            System.out.println("" + P1.X + "," + P1.Y);
            PlayerInfo P3 = new PlayerInfo();
            P3.setInfo(3);
            System.out.println("" + P1.X + "," + P1.Y);
            PlayerInfo P4 = new PlayerInfo();
            P4.setInfo(4);
            System.out.println("" + P1.X + "," + P1.Y);
```

Player Info is defined as:

```
public class PlayerInfo{
public static int Range;
public static int X;
public static int Y;
public static int Score;
public static int Lives;
private static ImageIcon image;
public PlayerInfo(int Num){
    Range = 1;
        if(Num == 1){
            this.X = 0;
            this.Y = 0;
            //System.out.println("" + X + "," + Y);
            image = new ImageIcon("H:\\My Pictures\\BomberMan\\BMBlack.png");
        }
        else if(Num == 2){
            this.X = 16;
            this.Y = 0;
            //System.out.println("" + X + "," + Y);
            image = new ImageIcon("H:\\My Pictures\\BomberMan\\BMWhite.png");
        }
        else if(Num == 3){
            this.X = 0;
            this.Y = 16;
            //System.out.println("" + X + "," + Y);
            image = new ImageIcon("H:\\My Pictures\\BomberMan\\BMRed.png");
        }
        else if(Num == 4){
            this.X = 16;
            this.Y = 16;
            //System.out.println("" + X + "," + Y);
            image = new ImageIcon("H:\\My Pictures\\BomberMan\\BMBlue.png");
        }
    Score = 0;
    Lives = 3;
}
```

Right now my code is displaying:

0,0

16,0

0,16

16,16

when it should be displaying:

0,0

0,0

0,0

0,0

because the P1.X and P1.Y are initialized as 0 and 0 and are not supposed to be changed in my code.
I have no idea why it is changing the P1.X and P1.Y values when I am not touching them at all. Can someone please explain this to me? Note: I have tried creating a separate method to set the information and an array of PlayerInfo's, but nothing works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the `if` clauses of `PlayerInfo` class you are assigning values to `X` and `Y`. For example:

```
 this.X = 0;
 this.Y = 0;
```

That is the reason why the values are changing because the `X` and `Y` variables are `static`.
Remove the `static` for both the variables in `PlayerInfo` and then you will get the behaviour you want.

`static` variables are shared across different objects of the class. So if you assigned `P1.X = 10`, then `P2.X`, `P3.X`, `P4.X`, etc will also become `10` as the same variable is shared by all the object.